# How to generate all binary matrix by permuting subdiagonal elements in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am interested in just considering changes to the the sub-diagonal entries as I always let the diagonal and upper-triangular entries be zero. The closed formula for the total number of permutations is given 2^( n choose 2 ). For the n=4 case I have

```
         d_1

        x(2,1)   d_2
   X=        
        x(3,1)  x(3,2)  d_3   

        x(4,1)  x(4,2) x(4,3)  d_4
```

where the upper triangular entries and the d_i's already equal zero.

I know there will be 64 different matrices, but how do I generate them for any n?

Comment: These are not permutations (ie reordering) but combination (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination). Otherwise I know nothing about Mathlab, Sorry.

Comment: Maybe [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) is of interest?

Comment: To have all possible orderings of the sub-diagonal elements you need to use permute them and use perms. However, this problem can be feasibly solved when the number of elements to permute is no more than 10 and this means n = 5. You need to elaborate a bit more what type of "combination" you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, figure out how to extract/emplace the subdiagonal elements.  How about just:

```
sub_idx = find(~triu(ones(n)));
```

Now use this vector of indices as the permanent mapping of binary values into your subdiagonal.  Now, all we need is a matrix of all possible binary values:

```
num_combs = 2^length(sub_idx);
binary_combs = dec2bin(0:num_combs-1).' - '0';
```

And now the k'th combination matrix is:

```
mtx = zeros(n);
mtx(sub_idx) = binary_combs(:,k);
```

(EDITING to add single output matrix option)

If you want them all in one big 3D matrix, then instead:

```
tmp = zeros(n*n, num_combs);
tmp(sub_idx, :) = binary_combs;
mtx = reshape(tmp, [n n num_combs]);
```

Comment: You can use `tril(...,-1)` to get sub-diagonal elements.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all download combn from the filexchange (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-combn-4-3)
2. This function should solve your problem (it uses combn from above). The output will be a 3-dimensional array.

tril_combs.m

```
function out = tril_combs(n)

n_combs = [n^2 - n]/2;
combs = combn([0 1], n_combs);
out = zeros(n, n, n_combs);

for mat = 1:size(combs,1)
    current = zeros(n);
    k = 0;
    for i = 2:n
        for j = 1:(i-1)
            k = k + 1;
            current(i,j) = combs(mat,k);
        end
    end
    out(:,:,mat) = current;
end
```